# How to restore a backup that was done simplistically by copying everything to an external hard drive with rsync?

Tags: backup, restore

I have a full copy of the hard drive I did with rsync. I maintain it updated and, if something goes really wrong, I can restore the laptop to the very exact state it had.

However, after installing a different Ubuntu version, I could not restore the backup any more, because some kind of "signature" (please forget my ignorance) in the hard drive had changed. After restoring the whole content of the hard drive and trying to reboot, I got something similar to "drive not found" and a combination of maybe eight to twelve four-digit numbers that, I believe, identify the partition or something...

I think I can tweak some ascii file inside the backup copy and change that number before restoring it, and it would work.

I appreciate if someone can fix the details of this information I am giving only very vaguely here. Thanks.

Comment: More details would be nice, but I'm guessing you're having issues because you overwrote the file /etc/fstab, which contains info about the OS's partitions, like the partition UUIDs, which are unique.

Comment: This is one reason why you should never ever restore a drive image, but only the parts you need. You've probably borked the install, but thankfully you can just reinstall and restore.

Comment: Hard to tell from what you posted. What did you back up and restore? Sounds like system files and not just data in home. You can not likely share system files across versions of Ubuntu easily. IMO I advise you only back up user data and any system files you manually edited. Makes smaller backups and system files are installed and maintained via apt

Comment: @WJAndrea Yes, I think it was that file.

Comment: if you run `sudo blkid` it should show you the UUID's of the drives/partitions installed .. check `/etc/fstab` to see if the UUIDs and partitions match .. if not .. make them match. If your root was UUID 8548xxxxxxxxxxx and now when you do `sudo blkid` it shows the root is UUID 8578xxxxxxxx  you will need to change the fstab so it shows the newer UUID. Of course the numbers I show are just examples and will be long numbers. If you arent familiar .. edit your post and add the contents of `/etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid` and someone will surely be able to tell you what you need to change